# Same keyboard shortcut for both resizing windows AND switching between monitors

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, windows, window-manager

I'm a looking for a solution (Gnone extension maybe ? Custom keyboard shortcut script ? ) to make the keyboard shortcut to switch between monitor similar to windows.
On windows, the user can resize windows **AND** switch between monitors with the same keyboard shortcut, `super + arrow_key`.
On gnome, the user must use 2 separate shortcut (respectively `super + arrow_key`, `super + shift + arrow_key` ).
Any idea how to achieve this ?
[image]